# Ubuntu the difference between sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get install?

Tags: apt

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?newwindow=1&ei=6GgJWtSFBYfOvgT6j4mwBg&q=ubuntu+difference+sudo+apt-get+upgrade+and+sudo+apt-get+install&oq=&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.35i39k1l6.103332.103332.0.156680.2.1.1.0.0.0.0.0..1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.97.6...92.g81BqpGcZTk) is little helpful so I asked here.

What is the difference between sudo `apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install`?

Comment: See man apt-get . upgrade will upgrade all of your installed packages. install will install your packages and dependencies or upgrade that single package and dependencies if it is already installed.

Comment: So it seems install cover the job of upgrade, right?

Comment: For `install` you have to point a package or packages you want to install or upgrade. `upgrade` checks all your *installed* packages and updates them if it's needed.

Comment: That is much clearer now. May you make it an answer so as to get accepted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short answer citing the comment by @Evgeniy Yanuk

For **`install`** you have to point a package or packages you want to install or upgrade. **`upgrade`** checks all your installed packages and updates them if it's needed.

### Update

- Update the list of all current program packages in the repositories in order to determine which packages are candidates for upgrading.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update   # old syntax
  sudo apt update       # new syntax
  ```

### Upgrade

- Upgrade all current program packages in the Ubuntu operating system, that are installed automatically or from the repositories or from a PPA.

  ```
  sudo apt-get upgrade  # old syntax
  sudo apt upgrade      # new syntax
  ```

  or if you want to upgrade and also perform checks and fixes to upgrade to a fully upgraded and compatible system (this is what I do),

  ```
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # old syntax
  sudo apt full-upgrade      # new syntax
  ```
- Install a program package, a new package that was not yet installed

  ```
  sudo apt-get upgrade  # old syntax
  sudo apt upgrade      # new syntax
  ```

### Update & Upgrade

- When you intend to upgrade the system (within the same version of Ubuntu), you can run **one of** the following command lines

  ```
  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
  sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```

### Install

- When you intend to install a new program package, you can run the following command lines. It is a good idea to update before installing.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update                        # old syntax
  sudo apt-get install program-package-name  # old syntax

  sudo apt update                            # new syntax
  sudo apt install program-package-name      # new syntax
  ```

---

**Edit:**

If you call **`apt install`** without any parameter (no package specified), it will tell you if there are packages to upgrade, but it will not upgrade anything.

**end of edit**

---

### Manual page

You find more details in the built-in manual

```
man apt-get  # old syntax
man apt      # new syntax
```

---

### Upgrade to a new version alias release of Ubuntu

This is a completely different task. It is complicated and risky. ***Backup*** everything that you don't want to lose before you start on this venture.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

You find more details in the built-in manual

```
man do-release-upgrade
```

This method works from a previous version to the next version. There is one exception: You can also `do-release-upgrade` from the previous LTS version to the next LTS version, for example

- from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS
- from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Before starting you should

- remove all PPAs and non-standard program packages (that do not belong to the Ubuntu repositories), because they can break the release-upgrade process,
- update & full-upgrade the current system, so that it is up to date.

### Install a fresh system

It is **often easier and faster to install a fresh system** than to **`do-release-upgrade`**, particularly if there are several steps, or if the new version is very different from the previous one.

Remember to ***backup*** everything that you don't want to lose before you start on this venture.

Comment: Thanks for full details though may you help to answer the OP

Comment: I added 'Short answer citing the comment by @Evgeniy Yanuk'. Maybe you, Evgenjy, want to make an own answer. In that case, please tell me if you want me to remove or modify my paragraph that is citing your comment.

Comment: I have further question - we can call `sudo apt install` without specifying any package, right. Then what is that different with `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: There is an *edit* replying to your latest comment.

Comment: I am flooded by your answer... If only you would make it clean and short. Any way, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I made the edit cleaner and shorter.

Comment: All is okay. I appreciate your work :)

Comment: Thanks a log, finally I got to understand all those differences