# Which LTS version is supported? 18.04.1 or 18.04.2? both?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, security

Source: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

The graph in that source page makes it look like Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (v4.15) will be supported for 5 years but Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS will only be supported for 6 or 9 months.

Source: https://ubuntubudgie.org/blog/2019/02/15/18-04-2-lts-ubuntu-budgie-released

> The LTS version is supported for 3 years while the regular releases are supported for 9 months.

^ I imagine that the LTS version they refer to is `18.04.1` and the regular releases they refer to is the `18.04.2`, `.3`, etc.

## Questions

1. Should I install 18.04.1 or 18.04.2?
2. If I'm on 18.04.2 and that LTS is only supported for 9 months, does that mean I need to do a `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to go to 18.04.3 in order to continue getting security updates?
3. If I'm on 18.04.1 and that LTS is supported for 5 years, does that mean I don't have to do a `sudo apt dist-upgrade` in order to continue receiving security updates?

Thank you

Comment: I prefer to stay with the original kernel series of each LTS version, so for 18.04 LTS the 4.15 kernel series. You get it not only from the 18.04 LTS iso file but also from the first point release, 18.04.1 LTS iso file. I will select a newer kernel series only if this original kernel series is not compatible with the computer's hardware.

Comment: the support is for 5 years since initial release.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful comments. So do I need to run a `dist-upgrade` before receiving security updates once 18.02.3 comes out?

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975968/ubuntu-the-difference-between-sudo-apt-get-upgrade-and-sudo-apt-get-install/976017#976017) may help you tell the differences between the different update and upgrade commands.

Comment: Ubuntu LTS version itself have 5 year support like GNOME.  Xubuntu LTS, Lubuntu LTS, Budgie LTS, etc have a 3 year support cycle.  You can always check the support cycle of your installed Ubuntu by running `ubuntu-support-status` from a terminal and that will tell you how much support you have.

Comment: In 18.04 LTS you are offered to select an automatic update & upgrade process. I run `sudo apt full-upgrade` manually to make it fully up to date (including kernels and checks for compatibilty). Some people think it is risky and prefer `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: @sudodus Ok. So hypothetically, let's say I have a service running on my ubuntu 18.04.2 server. Support for 18.04.2 has ended and I must upgrade to 18.04.3. Let's say I require zero downtime for my service. Do I require a `sudo apt full-upgrade` or `sudo apt upgrade` and a reboot before I can get security updates? or can I get security updates until the end of the 5 year support period without having to do a `dist-upgrade`?

Comment: For a **server** I would recommend  to stay with the original kernel series of each LTS version, so for 18.04 LTS the 4.15 kernel series. I would not tamper with upgrading the HWE (so I would avoid 18.04.2 ...). This reduces the risk. Upgrading without reboot means that you stay running the same kernel and only upgrade application and help programs/libraries (of course including security upgrades), so I think `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` is a good command line.

Comment: The tool `livepatch` is present in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS so it seems that the kernel can be upgraded/patched live (while the system is running). See [this link about linux](https://linux-audit.com/livepatch-linux-kernel-updates-without-rebooting/) and [that link about Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/livepatch).

Comment: Great! I understand your commendation to use 18.04 instead of 18.04.minor version. It seems that the major changes in the minor version updates involve the kernel and I should be able to get the latest security updates without having to go to the minor versions and without having to reboot (unless a kernel security is found). Is that correct? @sudodus

Comment: Yes, I think so. You can start from the first point release 18.04.1 LTS (which has the original kernel series and the kernel as well as application programs are debugged and polished). I am not a server guy, but I suggest that you explore `livepatch`. I think it can help keep your server running and upgraded for years without any downtime.

Answer (score 2):

The article might be a little misleading.

Version **18.10** is supported for 9 months.

It says **18.04** is supported for three more years because it is LTS. This includes 18.04.1, 18.04.2 and 18.04.3 when it comes out, etc. They would all be good until April of year 2021 according to comments below.

It says the advantage of **18.04.2** over **18.04.1** is some of the kernel and driver enhancements in **18.10** have been back-ported to **18.04.2**. In reality I'm on 16.04 and can install kernels and drivers newer than **18.10** as can anyone.

Comment: "*It says 18.04 is supported for three years*" is not wrong from the context. [The article](https://ubuntubudgie.org/blog/2019/02/15/18-04-2-lts-ubuntu-budgie-released) is about Ubuntu **Budgie**. Being a release of a community maintained flavour, Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 is actually supported for 3 years (not 5).

Comment: @pomsky I guess forcing them to upgrade 2 years earlier and work out the upgrade bugs makes those Budgies our "Canary in the Coal Mine" :) Thanks for the enlightenment. I've revised the answer.

Answer (score 1):

the 3rd number separated by dots is a minor revision.  installing either one will work.  when the install is finished and you reboot, log in, open a terminal, and do:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

to upgrade all packages to the latest Ubuntu revision.

*edit*:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

this works on any revision of any version of Ubuntu to get you to the latest revision of that version.  LTS versions have many revisions through their many years of support.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Desktop version 18.04 and Ubuntu Server version 18.04 from Canonical are supported through April of 2023 officially, as far as maintenance updates are concerned**.

18.04.1 and 18.04.2 are maintenance updates for 18.04. Meaning, 18.04.2 is just an updated version of 18.04. So it will also be supported through April of 2023.

Potentially for example, there might be an 18.04.9 version released in late 2022. If that happened, it would also be supported through April of 2023.

** The support timeline for hardware is different, but the same principles apply. The support window is defined based on the initial major release version and is not normally modified or extended as maintenance releases are made.